# Convert Percentage to Decimal Format WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, decimal, percentage

Any can Help me with this little problem..
i'm programing and validating a DatagridView in C# WinForms.
I have 2 Columns in a DataGridView.
1. Discount %.
2. Discount Decimal.

I want to do the next operation..

I have a article and his costprice is equals to $100.00,
If i put a value for example 10% in DatagridView.Rows.Column["Discount %"].Value.. 
Then, automatically converting that 10% in a decimal, it's mean the value in decimal 10% of $100 will be $10 and this value $10 automatically put into DatagridView.Rows.Column["Discount Decimal"].Value ...
Any can Help, because i have no idea how to do that and have headache trying to do with regex but not works  ? Thx in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the automatic conversion use LostFocus on the textbox

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter.aspx

For the decimal value this answer will help

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/85c5d6d2-1a79-4be7-8af6-7261d4172e74/convert-a-percentage-to-decimal?forum=csharpgeneral

Set the discount decimal text to the results from both of those links.